# Random select memory

Tags: jquery, html

I would like to add more images to the list where it randomly select an amount of images. as it is now, then all the images are shown on the list.
Any idea how I can do this?

Here is the is the list in HTML

```
<div id="sample">

    <!-- start: Memory Lætt -->
    <div class="kvilt-memory-game">
        <ul>
            <!-- back image (must be the first item) -->
            <li><img title="Click to reveal" src="img/back.png" /></li>
            <!-- match image (must be the second item) -->
            <li><img title="Match made" src="img/matched.jpg" /></li>               
            <!-- image figures (add as many as you want) -->
            <li><img id="ID01" title="Figure 01" src="img/ficard01.png" /></li>
            <li><img id="ID02" title="Figure 02" src="img/ficard02.png" /></li>
            <li><img id="ID03" title="Figure 03" src="img/fucard01.png" /></li>
            <li><img id="ID04" title="Figure 04" src="img/fucard02.png" /></li>


      </ul>
    </div>
```

And here is the script i execute

```
/* plugin methods */
var methods =
{

    /* intialization */
    init : function(options)
    {

        /* settings */
        var settings = 
        { 
            spacing: 10, /* space between items */
            columns: 4 /* number of columns */
        };
        return this.each(function()
        {

            var self = $(this), data = self.data('data');
            if(!data)
            {

                /* overwrite default settings */
                if (options && $.isPlainObject(options)) $.extend(settings, options);

                /* get unordered list */
                var list = self.find('ul').first();

                /* get images data */
                var datBack, datMatch, datFigs = [], numFigs, imgEl;
                list.find('img').each(function(i)
                {
                    imgEl = $(this);                        
                    if (i == 0) { datBack = { src: imgEl.attr('src'), title: imgEl.attr('title') }; }
                    else if (i == 1) { datMatch = { src: imgEl.attr('src'), title: imgEl.attr('title') }; }
                    else { datFigs.push({ src: imgEl.attr('src'), id: imgEl.attr('id'), title: imgEl.attr('title') }); }
                });
                datFigs = datFigs.concat(datFigs);
                numFigs = datFigs.length;

                /* init data */
                self.data('data',
                {
                    target: self, 
                    list: list,
                    settings: settings,                     
                    datBack: datBack,
                    datMatch: datMatch,
                    datFigs: datFigs,
                    numFigs: numFigs,
                    itmData: null, 
                    busy: false,
                    events: { init: $.Event('init'), match: $.Event('match'), done: $.Event('done'), reveal: $.Event('reveal'), fail: $.Event('fail') },
                    stats: { numClicks: 0, time: 0 },
                    matchCount: 0
                });

                /* generate items */
                methods._generate.call(self, self.data('data'));
            }
        });
```

Comment: This question cries out loud for a fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

If i'm not in a mistake, you've to create the html code with the JS script, because all html code is view. So you've to quit the images form html code, and make it when you need with the script.

I would make some functions to show each image, and then use toggle to show alternative each one. It's not random, but it's almost and you only have to choose with a random number which will be the first one, and with another random number the increment to look for the next image.

An example of how to uso toggle to use alternative functions:

```
$("p").toggle(function(){
alert("You've activated the first function now");
},function(){
alert("Now it's the second one");
});
```

This will runs with all "p" objects in your html, as $("p") makes.